# How to keep the position of each scroll of each page independent of the scroll modification of other pages in shinydashboard?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shinydashboard app with multiple pages. However, whenever I leave page A and enter page B and then come back to A, the scroll position of A affects the scroll position B.

I would like to avoid this (ie, that the scrolls are independent)?

**I could even put some reproducible code, but it would be too big to put it here.
So I figured it would be better to insert a stable shinydashboard app inside shinyGallery**:

https://ctmm.shinyapps.io/ctmmweb/

Note that the scrolls are not in the previous position when I change pages in the sidebar.

I would like each scroll of each page to be independent of the scroll of others.

I tried to insert some `CSS` and `JS` code in my app (a `golem`) but I couldn't get the scrolls to be independent of each other for each page.

I believe all shinydashboards show this pattern...

**Each page was supposed to keep its position, no matter how many pages I entered later and returned to it.**

### EDIT

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", titleWidth = 320)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 320,
  
  sidebarMenu(
    
    menuItem(
      text = "A1", 
      tabName = "st1"
    ),
    menuItem(
      text = "A2",
      menuSubItem(
        text = "AA1",
        tabName = "nd2"
      ),
      menuSubItem(
        text = "AA2", 
        tabName = "rd3"
      ), 
      menuSubItem(
        text = "AA3", 
        tabName = "th4"
      )
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  HTML(
  "<head>
  <style>
  .small-box {
  height: 500px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>"
  ),
  
  tabItems(
    
    tabItem(
      tabName = "st1", 
      
      fluidPage(
        column(
          width = 6, 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow")
        )
      )
    ), 
    
    tabItem(
      tabName = "nd2", 
      
      fluidPage(
        column(
          width = 6, 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow")
        )
      )
    ), 
    
    tabItem(
      tabName = "rd3", 
      
      fluidPage(
        column(
          width = 6, 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow")
        )
      )
    ), 
    
    tabItem(
      tabName = "th4", 
      
      fluidPage(
        column(
          width = 6, 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow"), 
          valueBox(value = 500, subtitle = "stack overflow")
        )
      )
    )
    
  )
  
  
  
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header = header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[App link](https://overflow.shinyapps.io/test/).

Comment: That is the natural behavior of a SPA (Single Page Application) where the URL does not changes/load a new page. Data is loaded asynchronously and inject into the page. 

If the website loaded individual pages then the browser would be able to remember and restore scroll position. If you want individual scrolling then you need to add JavaScript that adds event listeners for the menu-links which then registers the scrolling position on click and restores them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, what would that JavaScript look like? Could you point me to something or answer this question with some code? I thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will keep track of the scroll position of each menuitem ("page") and restore the scroll position when you go back to a page that was previously scrolled.

A video demonstrating the script can viewer here:

https://vimeo.com/761038827

```
// CSS selector to find menu items to track excluding treeview/expandbutton
var menuItemsSelector = "ul.sidebar-menu li:not(.treeview)";

// Set a delay (ms) when restoring position giving page time to generate contents
var delayBeforeRestoringPosition = 50;

// ### ### ### ### ###

// Overwrite console.log to prevent other messages from appearing in the log
// Only messages starting with "*" with go through - example "*Hello" prints only "Hello"
consolelog = console.log;
console.log = function(message) { if (message.indexOf("*") == 0) consolelog(message.substring(1)); }



// Keep track of clicked menuitems and their scroll positions
var arrMenuPosition = [];

// Keep track of scrolling status
var isScrolling = false;

// Keep track of current/active menuitem to save scroll position
var currentMenuItem = null;

// Get text of current menu item
var getCurrentMenuItemText = () => { return currentMenuItem.textContent.trim(); }

// Handler scroll actions (save and restore)
var scrollHandler = (save, positionOrElement) => {
    
    if (save)
    {
        // Get new position in window
        var newPosition = positionOrElement;
        
        // Get text of current menuitem which is used to track the menuitem
        let text = getCurrentMenuItemText();
        
        // Save position of current menuitem
        arrMenuPosition[text] = newPosition;

        console.log(`*Page '${text}' was set to position ${newPosition}`);      

    } else {
        
        // Register current menuitem
        currentMenuItem = positionOrElement;
        
        // Get text of current menuitem which is used to track the menuitem
        let text = getCurrentMenuItemText();
        console.log("*Menu click, new text is " + text);
        
        // Get last known scroll position of current or 0 if not available
        let position = arrMenuPosition[text] ?? 0;
        
        // Scroll window to position
        setTimeout( () => {
            isScrolling = true;
            window.scrollTo(0, position);
        }, delayBeforeRestoringPosition);
        
        console.log("*Scroll window to position " + position);
    }
}

// Setup
var setupIndividualScrollers = () => {
    // Get a list of all menuitems
    let menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(menuItemsSelector);
    
    // If the length of the list is 0 then the menuitems are not yet available
    if (menuItems.length == 0)
    {
        // If this script is executed before the menuitems have been generated,
        // wait for them to be available - call this function again in 100 ms
        setTimeout(setupIndividualScrollers, 100);
    } else {
        console.clear();
        console.log(`*Console clear to make output more visible.`);
        
        // Loop through all menuitems
        menuItems.forEach(li => {
            
            // Add event listener for each menuitem
            li.addEventListener("click", function() {
                
                // Scroll position based on menu item that was clicked
                scrollHandler(false, this);
                
            });
        });
        
        // Set current menuitem to the first menuitem
        currentMenuItem = document.querySelector(menuItemsSelector);
        
        // Add event listener on window for scroll event
        document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
            
            // Save new position if call did not come from menu item change:
            if (isScrolling == false) scrollHandler(true, window.scrollY);
            
            // Reset scroll status
            isScrolling = false;
            
        });
    }
};
// Make initial call to function
setupIndividualScrollers();
```

Comment: doesn't work, the pages are still affected by the previous ones. I believe it has to be a specific solution for the `shiny`.

Comment: @neves I noticed that the restore-code could be executed before the browser had a chance to change all the content when you change pages. I have therefore added a delay of 50 ms - you may modified this if you want. Please copy and paste the new code.

Comment: @neves I have also noticed a strange browser behavior. The page "Introduction" is short and the browser often does not trigger the scrolling-event unless I resize the window to a height where there are 2 scrollbars (one for the page and one for the contents).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the scrolls from the previous page are inherited when I enter a new page. These scrolls must be independent. If, for example, on `page A` I scroll to the end of it and then go to `page B` and scroll halfway, when I go back to A the scroll should be there at the end (previous position of it).

Comment: @neves That is exacly what the script does. How are you adding/executing the code? How are you testing the code? I assume it is the same app (meaning URL) ?

Comment: @neves I have recorded a video to demonstrate -- Please note that the video will automatically be deleted in 24 hours: https://www.veed.io/view/b467b12a-9c15-4225-a0bb-66501a5c09ce/showcase?sharingWidget=true

Comment: It worked. On a standard `shinydashboard`, what you should do is replace the `"#side_menus li"` to `".sidebar-menu li"`. However, it doesn't work for menu sub items, ie when I expand the options (treeview) of ".sidebar-menu li". I edited my code with a default shinydashboard. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @neves I have worked with the resource you have provided ( https://ctmm.shinyapps.io/ctmmweb/ ) and there are no sub items in the menu, nor have sub items been mentioned in the original post. The selector "#side_menus li" works fine with the resource.

Comment: @neves I believe this answer does in fact answer the original post. Please accept the answer and possibly create a new question containing the actual scenario you are working with so developers know what problem to solve.

Comment: @neves, I was just thinking about your subitems. If you replace arrMenuPosition[text] with arrMenuPosition[currentMenuItem] and drop all related to "text" then it should work with subitems since it saves the element (LI) and detects it in the array.

Comment: I will accept the answer. I also figured you don't have access to R, so I've uploaded [this](https://overflow.shinyapps.io/test/) application so you can give me a last bit of help on the nmenu item (`treeview`). All pages, including those in these submenus, must be independent of the others. I'm grateful for helping me.

Comment: @neves Change both selectors to: `ul.sidebar-menu li:not(.treeview)`

Comment: @neves I have updated the script to use a variable for the selector and moved modifiable variables to the beginning of the script.